# Import SSH keys for remote server

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, git

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 X64 and I am working on a project for which I am trying out GIT. I have created a repo on one of our remote servers, which is a Debian server, and the repo is accessible via SSH from command line as well as from Intellij. 
If you need any info, please let me know

[image]

I am trying to access it via a GIT-UI tool called `GitGraken`. It is looking for ssh keys for our remote server. How can I get those keys and add it for my user on the system so I can keep an eye on the repository. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a ssh keypair in the terminal with the command: 
`ssh-keygen`. Then you have to add the public key(.pub).

see `man ssh-keygen` for more options

Comment: Shouldn't there already exist a key on the server as it's running an open-ssh server? Shouldn't I add it?

Comment: @WeareBorg no, installing SSH doesn't automatically create a keypair for you. You have to do so with `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: @user68186, yes, thx! Ive edited my post. sorry for that issue.  .pub --> Public Key. Never share or transfer your private key

Answer (score 2):

Use `ssh-copy-id`

If your local machine has the `ssh-copy-id` script installed, you can use it to install your public key to any user that you have login credentials for.

Run the `ssh-copy-id` script by specifying the user and IP address of the server that you want to install the key on, like this:

```
ssh-copy-id demo@SERVER_IP_ADDRESS
```

Comment: I get an error : /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found

Answer (score 1):

Finally, [this](https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh) link from debian helped. I created a key first with following command on my local machine :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then I copied contents of the public key(/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) into authorized keys on the server. 
After that I was able to login without password and solve the problem.

Comment: Isn't this what the other two answers tell you to do?

Comment: @muru : DanG's did, but was not detailed enough. But was helpful.. I have accepted it as the answer. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Actually copying the key to `authorized_keys` on the remote server is `ssh-copy-id`'s job.

Comment: @muru : It is not working though, that's the first thing I tried after creating the key, dunno why its failing.

Comment: I guess it is pointless now that you have copied the key, but does `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` throw any errors?

Comment: @muru I get this error:  /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname /home/akshay/.ssh/id_rsa: Name or service not known

Comment: I guess you're using an old version of `ssh-copy-id` which doesn't support the `-i` flag. Ah, well. Probably some bug that's fixed in later versions.

Comment: @muru : Just installed ssh-copy-id, so don't think its a version issue.

Comment: Did you add server where that key will be copied? `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@<ip-or-domain>`

Comment: @Gen : The -i parameter just specifies the path from which the file is to be copied, I didn't specify that as the remote server user had the file in correct location with correct name...